# ngFor over a large array

Tags: angular, sequelize.js

everyone,

I am working on an angular application, and have basically and input which displays names form a database table as option.
I manage the database connection with sequelize.

The fact is my table contains a huge amount of names, and when i set no limit to my sequelize.findall(), i am facing an issue.
The compilation is done and i can launch the application, but when coming to the component which loads the names content, it simply bugging and can not load the page.

Is this a problem with sequelize, which can not load all the data form the database? can we thus increase the execution memory?

Or it is my angular which can t display everything>

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can use virtual scroll for that https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-demo-virtual-scroll

Comment: Consider using technologie like Pagination or Virtual Scrolling

Comment: thanks for helping first :)

So when i import it in app.module.ts i got the error that :

@angular/cdk/scrolling"' has no exported member 'ScrollingModule'

and so far i have checked on the internet, this seems the way to import it, even in angular 7 i am using...

Comment: For Angular 7 you need to import `ScrollDispatchModule`, `ScrollingModule` is for Angular 8. (Source: https://v7.material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api)

Comment: Thanks, after importing that i get that <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport> is not a known element..